# BeanPostProcessor can't process bean RedisProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

The verion of spring boot which I use is 2.1.5.RELEASE.
My project work with redis.For security,I encrypt my redis password.I set value in my application.properties as follows：

> spring.redis.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I want to decrypt before spring bean's init,so I want to change the value of RedisProperties's **passowrd** property.So I customize a BeanPostProcesser like this:

```
@Component
public class PasswordBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Autowired
    private Cryptor cryptor;

    @Value("${spring.redis.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        log.info("beanName = {}",beanName);
        if (bean instanceof RedisProperties) {
            RedisProperties redisPropertiesBean = (RedisProperties) bean;
            try {
                redisPropertiesBean.setPassword(cryptor.decrypt(password));
                log.debug(redisPropertiesBean.getPassword());
                return redisPropertiesBean;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("redis password decrypt error", ex);
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

But this didnot work well,when I run my application ,there is no log like this print:

> beanName = redisProperties

To make sure there is a bean named `redisProperties` in my `applicationContext`,I inject bean `RedisProperties` to another Bean.It work well ,I can get properties in `RedisProperties`.

To make my application run success with encrypt password,I decrypt redis's password in another's `@PostConstruct` method.But I think this way is not graceful,what is the right way?

who can help me，please

Comment: Check out this link: https://threadminions.com/2018/07/23/encryption-decryption-of-properties-in-spring-boot-with-jasypt/

Comment: I think you shoud follow @MarkBramnik suggestion, I was about to write same in answer

Comment: @Mark Bramnik thank you for your help.I have look through this page ,but in my company,the encryption way already has been specified，I can't use jasypt.I alse want to know why my BeanPostProcesser not invoke in this bean `RedisProperties`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understood that jasypt can't be used.
However, take a look at its source code which is fairly simple, given the fact you already work with Bean Post Processors which is a fairly advanced stuff in spring / spring boot

It's starter (autoconfig module) is available [Here](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/tree/master/jasypt-spring-boot-starter)

So you'll see that it has `spring.factories` that enable some bootstrap  and autoconfigurations.

Eventually you'll come to the code [that actually handles the encryption](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot/blob/3715d61d9a887ab471eeb52434cd13fcffec50f2/jasypt-spring-boot/src/main/java/com/ulisesbocchio/jasyptspringboot/configuration/EnableEncryptablePropertiesBeanFactoryPostProcessor.java)

It uses a bean factory post processor - something that kicks in when the bean definitions are ready but the actual beans have not been created yet. This is a hook that micht be relevant to you. Of course the implementation will be different but the "orchestration" is the same...